# How to calculate the limit using the fundamental limit (without L'Hopital's rule)

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate the limit:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{\alpha h}-1}{e^{\beta h}-1}$$ with $\alpha, \beta\in \Bbb R$.

Using the following fundamental limit:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}=1$$

I need to calculate it without using L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations. Images are harder to read

Comment: Hint: multiply and divide by $\alpha \beta.$

Comment: I suggest dividing  the numerator by $\alpha h$ and denominator by $\beta h.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*On the suggestion of @Sean Roberson*.

We know that

$$\lim_{f(h)\to 0}\frac{e^{f(h)}-1}{f(h)}=1$$

Now if $h\to 0$ also $\alpha h\to 0$. Same for $\beta$ i.e. $\beta h\to 0$. Multiplying and dividing by $\alpha\beta$ both of which are different from zero, we obtain:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{\alpha h}-1}{e^{\beta h}-1}\,\frac{\beta\alpha}{\alpha\beta}$$
and rearranging,

$$\lim_{\alpha h\to 0}\frac{e^{\alpha h}-1}{\alpha h}\cdot\lim_{\beta h\to 0}\frac{\beta h}{e^{\beta h}-1}\cdot\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=1\cdot 1\cdot \frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$

Comment: I get it, thank you so much.